# Is running out of memory in Node an indication of a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've recently been studying some of my previous code and not sure where the memory leak is exactly coming form (if any). I seem to be running out of mem quite a lot and I'm sure there is an easier way around this? I initially thought creating the object every second (checkProducts gets called every second) was the issue however I am referencing the product in cache() so.
Thank you.

```
const checkProducts = async () => {
  console.log("Checking for new products");
  const proxyF = rProxy()
  console.log("PROXY " + proxyF.auth.username)
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://www.sizeofficial.fr/campaign/New+In/?facet:new=latest&sort=latest", { proxy });
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    $("li").each((i, elm) => {
      const title =
        $(elm)
          .find("a")
          .text() + "";
      const price = $(elm)
        .find(".pri")
        .text();
      const link = $(elm)
        .find(".itemImage")
        .attr("href");
      const quickBuy = $(elm)
        .find(".itemQuickView.quickView.btn.btn-default")
        .attr("data-quickview-path");
      const image = $(elm)
        .find("source")
        .attr("data-srcset");
      if (title !== "" && price !== "") {
        const product = {
          title: title.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace(/\t/g, ""),
          price: price,
          link: "https://www.sizeofficial.fr" + link,
          quickBuy: "https://www.sizeofficial.fr/" + quickBuy,
          image: image
        };
        cache(product);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  restocks.map(restock => checkRestock(restock));
};
```

Comment: @Dominic Thanks for the response. The restock list isn't long at all, maybe like 5 items at most. Also would you mind pointing out the list I'm recreating?

Comment: @Dominic omgggg, I am recreating it each time. It should be forEach not map. Perhaps this could be the cause?

Comment: Why are you doing it on the backed? Generally your UI should request pure data as JSON and render out the list in a library which can intelligently update list nodes like React. Cheerio is slow and not well suited to this, if there are only 5 items it does sound like it could be a leak

Comment: @Dominic Well, this site isn't in my control nor do they have a public API. Also, just checked there was 0 items in the restocks list.